# Why is my Photoshop text default to raster? I can't make it default vector/editable

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, raster

When i type in photoshop, it makes a quickmask, and lets me type, adjust.. but then when i commit -- it  becomes a selectable type layer that i have to fill. Don't know how i lost the default of plain vector based type??

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're on Horizontal Type Mask Tool instead of regular Type Tool. Hold down on the Type tool in the Menu and go back to the regular one. Or you can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> until it cycles to the regular which should be one click (since horizontal type mask is the last option, and regular type is the first)